# What type of connection does a Macbook Pro DVD Drive use?

Tags: macbook-pro, dvd

My DVD drive isn't working at the moment. I attempted to put another drive in instead, but that didn't work either. My friend suggested that there might be a problem with the connection. What type of connection do I have to obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [one here](http://www.powerbookmedic.com/MacBook-Pro-Optical-Drive-Cable-Superdrive-Cable-15-p-17058.html) for a hefty $28.95, though you might find a cheaper one by shopping around.

Comment: It's interesting that powerbook medic only shows one type of superdrive connector regardless of what MBP model you choose.  I have a first gen 2.0GHz machine and I know for sure that it uses a different connector than the one linked, but they are sayng it's compatible with my model... but there's at least 2 different types of connectors.  I'd assume 1 is for SATA (serial-ATA... the one linked by Tim) and one is for the older parallel ata/ide (the one I was referring to above).

Comment: Is [this one](http://cgi.ebay.com.au/MACBOOK-A1181-OPTICAL-DRIVE-CABLE-APPLE-821-0408-A-/130446044367?pt=AU_Computers_Apple_Parts_Accessories&hash=item1e5f30accf) any good? It says that it is a connector for an A1181 optical drive